# Android studio activity "template"

Tags: android, android-studio, e-commerce

I'm trying to create a shopping cart app for practice. Right now, I have a list view with products, and upon clicking each product it brings me to a different activity.

However, each product activity is very similar - the only things different being text, images, and the add to cart button. If I had more products, is there any way to create 1 product activity for use on each product?

Comment: You can start the product activity and pass an identifier specific for each product. Then you can load the product activity content depending on the identifier.

Answer (score 0):

You can try activity+fragment.

Comment: do not post comments as answers if you do not have enough reputation to  comment!

Answer (score 0):

Use [extras](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtra(java.lang.String,%20android.os.Parcelable)) to pass the data to the Activity in the [Intent](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) you use to start it.